# Gratis tool to visualize project dependencies for Visual Studio 2013 solution

Tags: gratis, data-visualization, code-analysis, visual-studio

Visual Studio *Ultimate* contains a [way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx) to visualize project dependencies for a solution. I do not have access to that edition (I have Pro, but am looking for a solution that will also work when using Express editions).

So, what would you recommend for visualizing project dependencies for a VS2013 solution?

**Must Haves:**

- Free of charge / **Gratis**. (Free trial doesn't cut it.)
- Runs on **Windows 8 and 8.1**.
- Able to handle **VS2013 solutions and above**;
- Able to handle a **mix of VB and C# projects**;
- Able to handle **circular dependencies** (I know, I know. Legacy, okay!? :D);
- Can deal with **smurf naming**. (Legacy modules have rather long names at times, starting with the same 20ish characters. I don't mind seeing the full names, but if project names are truncated with ellipsis after 30 characters, or if boxes become unwieldingly wide, this would be a problem.)
- Able to handle **100+ projects** in one solution.
- Must be **useful**. (Okay, I could use some help rewording this requirement to a less subjective summary, but here I mean to convey the fact that the visualization will be used for analyzing a decently sized codebase and creating greater understanding, as oppossed to e.g. a visualization that's purely for showing off / creating a poster for your office wall...)

**Nice to haves:**

- Runs on *Windows 7*.
- Also works in Visual Studio 2012.
- *Pretty* diagrams.
- *Low learning curve*, e.g. easy to get started.
- Ability to *rearrange* the various projects in the graph.
- Ability to *group* various projects.
- Ability to *save* the result in some format (that allows further edits/updates after reopening). (Exporting to PNG/PDF/SVG less important)

**What have I tried: / considered**

Well, what I've tried? To be honest: nothing yet. A [search](https://www.google.nl/search?q=open%20source%20dependency%20graph%20visual%20studio%20solution) or [two](https://www.google.nl/search?q=gratis%20dependency%20graph%20visual%20studio%20solution) gives me some options:

- [Visual Studio Ultimate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453.aspx), which I don't have.
- [Dependency Visualizer](http://dependencyvisualizer.codeplex.com/), which dates from 2008, and does not seem to run in my scenario. The context menu is missing, and calling it from the console says the solution isn't a VS 2005 or 2008 solution (which is correct in fact, I have a *2012* sln).
- [Resharper 8](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R8_vs2013.html)'s "[Project Dependency Graph](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vi_HgZ9U5uA)", which is not gratis. (To be honest, I have version 7, and was considering an upgrade anyway. But that's besides this softwarerecs question for me.)
- [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx), which is not gratis.
- [VSGraph](http://www.nichesoftware.co.nz/page/500/vsgraph), which may fit the bill, but the GraphViz dependency scares me (it's a great tool, but I fear a lot of manual labor here; that fear may well be irrational though).

In short, I haven't tried much yet. Instead I used my first bit of time to write the above question and ask the experts: what would you recommend?

Answer (score 5):

[Solution Dependency Viewer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b11824d0-d942-4863-99f8-e1884f26387a) by Microsoft for Visual Studio 2013.

> Solution Dependency Viewer provides a graph layer to the solution with
>   projects represented as nodes and project references represented as
>   links between nodes.

It seems to fill at least half of your requirements:

- Free (gratis)
- It runs on at least Windows 7 - 10 (as does Visual Studio 2013)
- It handles Visual Studio 2013 solutions (maybe more because it uses the IDE and MSBuild)
- It parses all C++, C#, and VB projects in the solution

Here is a sample with a small solution:

[image: Solution Dependency Viewer basic sample]